# Facebook oauth dialog showing by default for a new user, on iframe app

Tags: facebook, iframe, oauth

Today i have just noticed something weird at my facebook iframe app. Here is the workflow i am encountering:

1. I have never used the app before, im a first time user (ie deauthorized the app before)
2. I go to apps.facebook.com/myapp  - this is not the real facebook app im talking, is just for sake of example.
3. The app now redirects automatically to this: http://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fmyapp%2F&response_type=none&display=page. Is actually redirecting to the approve app dialog.

**The problem**: Until today, the app wasnt automatically redirecting to auth dialog; instead i was showing a welcome screen where i had a button Join, and on click on that button i was redirecting user to approve the app.

So whats happening, why its automatically redirecting? Is because facebook changed something? Or maybe a wrong setting in app settings?

Thanks in advance,
Marius B.

**EDIT**:
Found the problem...so here it goes.
It seems that in app settings even if i did not had Enhanced Auth Dialog option enabled, for some reason the Authenticated Referrals option was active.

**Solution**: Go to Settings->Advanced, and enable Enhanced Auth Dialog option, then go to Settings->OAuth Dialog and disable Authenticated Referrals option from bottom. Then go back to Settings->Advanced and disable the Enhanced Auth Dialog option.

Hope it helps.